# Characteristic Function and Density Function

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, self-learning, complex-integration

Consider a random variable $X$ with density function $f(x)$, moment generating function $M(t):= \int e^{tx}f(x) dx$ (existing in an interval containing $0$), cumulant generating function $K(t):=\log M(t)$ and characteristic function $\rho(t):= M(it)$. Then I read the following equations.

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty M(it)e^{-itx} dt \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots(1)\\
     &= \frac{n}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} M(nT)e^{-nTx} dT \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdot(2)\\
     &= \frac{n}{2\pi i}\int_{\tau-i\infty}^{\tau+i\infty} M(nT)e^{-nTx} dT \cdots\cdots\cdots(3),
\end{align}

where $\tau$ is any real number in the interval where $M(t)$ exists. I understand that $(1)$ is the inverse Fourier transform; $(2)$ is change of variable by setting $it=nT$. **However, I do not know why we want to do $(2)$ in the first place. Moreover, I do not know how to get $(3)$ and why we want to do that. I have not done complex analysis. Could anyone explain these in a more intuitive way, if possible, please? Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment generating function is the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of the probability density function. So, $f_X(x) \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\leftrightarrow} M_X(t)= E[e^{t X}]$ where $t$ is complex. The characteristic function is the [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $f_X(x)$: $\phi_X(\omega) = E[e^{i \omega X}] = M_X(i \omega)$.

The inverse Laplace transform is given by the [Bromwich integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula), which says you can integrate the Laplace transform weighted by an exponential along any line in the complex plane with constant real part in order to recover the original function. Unfortunately, you need to know some complex analysis to get this (for (3)).

So, in (1), you take the inverse Laplace transform by integrating along the imaginary axis. Equivalently, when you plug in $t = i \omega$, the Moment generating function becomes the characteristic function (which is the Fourier transform of the density), and thus you take an inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mean that due to some theorem(s) in complex analysis, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equal, please? If so, what is the name of the theorem, please? Moreover, if $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equal, why do we need $(3)$, please? Is it because $(3)$ might be easier to integrate than $(2)$ or something?

Comment: Click the Bromwich integral link. The region which the moment generating function exists always includes the imaginary axis. (3) is just the definition of the inverse Laplace transform, so its akin to asking "why do we need moment generating functions if we have characteristic functions?". You can do things like large deviations through moment generating functions, which makes them useful.